# Understanding calling of jQuery functions/feedback on beginner's small responsive layout script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, responsive-design

A while back I pieced together a small script that moves/resizes horizontally and vertically centered divs on a page based on window size for a kind of responsive design via jQuery, an alternative to CSS media queries. I'm dusting off the script and working on it as something I could put into a project portfolio, eventually to show at a job interview or something.

I'm trying to understand how my jQuery function calls are working. As I understand it, my function should be called in two ways (when the page is loaded and anytime the browser window is resized). It appears to me my function is being called in three different ways in my script below, but there's probably something I'm misunderstanding (as removing any of the three elements I've marked below seems to break the script):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //FIRST FUNCTION CALL ON PAGE LOAD?

    function divresize() {
        var contentwidth = $('#innerbox').width();
        var contentheight = $('#innerbox').height();
        if ((contentheight) < '700'){
            $('.background').css('height',contentheight * 1.15)
            $('.background').css('margin-top',-contentheight * .09)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('top',contentheight * .1925)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('height',contentheight * .24449)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('top',contentheight * .2325)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('height',contentheight * .24449)
            $('.nav').css('top',contentheight * .293)
            $('.nav').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.nav').css('height',contentheight * .03224)
            }
        if ((contentheight) >= '700'){ 
            $('.background').css('height',contentheight)
            $('.background').css('margin-top',-contentheight * .005)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('top',contentheight * .2423)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('height',contentheight * .2126)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('top',contentheight * .2773)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('height',contentheight * .2126)
            $('.nav').css('top',contentheight * .3258975)
            $('.nav').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.nav').css('height',contentheight * .0280374)
            }
    }

    divresize();  //ANOTHER FUNCTION CALL ON PAGE LOAD?

    $(window).bind("resize", function(){
        divresize(); //THIRD FUNCTION CALL? ON WINDOW RESIZE
    });

});
```

Is there duplicative/sloppy code here that would be good to clean up? Or am I misunderstanding how this is working?

I'm open to any other general feedback on how to refine the script. I'm getting the window height and width by reading the pixel height and width of a container div (#innerbox) set to 100% height and width and adjusting everything based off of that; there's probably a better way of doing this. Right now the script only adjusts things based on window height but it should do it based on width too.

Comment: Your function declaration does not execute/call the function

Comment: So the first line I have flagged isn't calling the function, it's just declaring it and stating it should be available when the document is ready?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: bad practice to constantly search the dom for same selector over and over when you can store reference to that element/collection once and use the reference more than once. Dom searches are expensive. Also all those css calls can be consolidated into one call per selector and a big object for each as argument. Will make it easier to read and more DRY. See css() api docs for 2 different ways to pass in values

Comment: Cool, thanks @LegenJerry!

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl . So you're saying I should store each of my CSS classes I'm referencing (.background, .thumbrow1, etc.) as variables and use the variables instead of referencing objects each time by CSS class?

I think I can see how to consolidate the CSS calls; what do you mean by "a big object for each as argument?"

Comment: Yes exactly...along lines of `var $back= $('.background')` ... then `$back.css({prop1:value1, prop2: value2, prop3:value3})`

Comment: And in fact only difference between the two conditions is the multipliers which could also be a way to consolidate repeating code. One css call only for each selector after you set multipliers as variables in the `if()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some additions that may improve your script

With jQuery's `.css()` method you can pass in an object of css properties, instead of multiple calls to the same method and selector.

You can immediately invoke the function using `(function name(par1, par2){//do code}(myVal1,myVal2));` If you would like it to execute on `$(document).ready()`

Also like one other user stated you can store the values of the `$('#innerbox').height()` and `$('#innerbox').width()` as variables outside your function if they are not changing. If they do change then you will need to call width and height methods on every function call.

**NOTE:**

If you are basing your resize on the `window` width and height instead of a child elements width and height you have the option to use `window.matchMedia` in your javascript. It functions the same as media queries in css. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp . Also, whenever possible, you should try to use css to change the layout based on a window resize, as excessive function calls in javascript can potentially have a negative impact on the user experience. In reality, browser resizes aren't common enough to warrant `window resize`. This could be done just in css with `variables` and `calc` (browser support is pretty good).

In essence your audience with the resize event is just people viewing it on desktop and making the window smaller or larger. Doesn't really have much impact on mobile devices. You could instead consider a [fluid layout](https://theblog.adobe.com/creating-fluid-layouts-images-with-css/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elWidth = $("#innerbox").width();
  var elHeight = $("#innerbox").height();

  (function divresize(width, height) {
    var contentwidth = width;
    var contentheight = height;
    if (contentheight < "700") {
      $(".background").css({
        "height": contentheight * 1.15,
        "margin-top": -contentheight * 0.09,
      });
      $(".thumbrow1").css({
        "top": contentheight * 0.1925,
        "margin-top": 0,
        "height": contentheight * 0.24449,
      });
      $(".thumbrow2").css({
        "top": contentheight * 0.2325,
        "margin-top": 0,
        "height": contentheight * 0.24449,
      });
      $(".nav").css({
        "top": contentheight * 0.293,
        "margin-top": 0,
        "height": contentheight * 0.03224,
      });
    }
    if (contentheight >= "700") {
      $(".background").css({
        "height": contentheight,
        "margin-top": -contentheight * 0.005,
      });
      $(".thumbrow1").css({
        "top": contentheight * 0.2423,
        "margin-top": 0,
        "height": contentheight * 0.2126,
      });
      $(".thumbrow2").css({
        "top": contentheight * 0.2773,
        "margin-top": 0,
        "height": contentheight * 0.2126,
      });
      $(".nav").css({
        "top": contentheight * 0.3258975,
        "margin-top": 0,
        "height": contentheight * 0.0280374,
      });
    }
  })(elWidth, elHeight); // IMMEDIATE INVOKED FUNCTION CALL USING "()"

  $(window).bind("resize", function() {
    divresize(elWidth, elHeight); //SECOND FUNCTION CALL ON RESIZE
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LegenJerry. Yeah #innerbox height and width change; #innerbox is set via CSS outside the script as 100% height and width of the body, and then I'm reading that height and width to get the window size and manipulating things based off of that. But instead of doing this there's probably a way of just directly getting the window height and width and working with that?

Comment: @J.Quest Yes this is build into javascript `window.innerWidth;` and `window.innerHeight;`

Comment: Thanks @LegenJerry! Also, agreed that CSS is a good way to accomplish this and provides a multitude of tools to do so between media queries, calc(), units like vh, vw, vmin, etc etc.

Can you think of anything responsive layout-wise that would be better or only possible via jQuery? Maybe I could turn this script into something more practical rather than just a proof of concept

Answer (score 0):

I've added comments within the JavaScript snippet to clarify each part of the code. I hope this helps in your understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
// This is a jQuery function that fires once the DOM (the html document) 
// is fully loaded/rendered. This ensures that all divs are on the 
// page before calling any code on it.

    function divresize() {
    // here you define the divresize function. 
    // The compiler knows divresize is available and can be called. 
    // However, it is not executed yet.
        var contentwidth = $('#innerbox').width();
        var contentheight = $('#innerbox').height();
        if ((contentheight) < '700'){
            $('.background').css('height',contentheight * 1.15)
            $('.background').css('margin-top',-contentheight * .09)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('top',contentheight * .1925)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('height',contentheight * .24449)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('top',contentheight * .2325)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('height',contentheight * .24449)
            $('.nav').css('top',contentheight * .293)
            $('.nav').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.nav').css('height',contentheight * .03224)
            }
        if ((contentheight) >= '700'){ 
            $('.background').css('height',contentheight)
            $('.background').css('margin-top',-contentheight * .005)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('top',contentheight * .2423)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow1').css('height',contentheight * .2126)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('top',contentheight * .2773)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.thumbrow2').css('height',contentheight * .2126)
            $('.nav').css('top',contentheight * .3258975)
            $('.nav').css('margin-top',0)
            $('.nav').css('height',contentheight * .0280374)
            }
    }

    divresize();
    // Here you call the divresize function and any code within is is executed.

    // Below you add a 'watch' function to window. 
    // It fires when window is resized. Any code within it is triggered on a resize. 
    // As you placed the resize function in it, it will execute the code within divresize()
    $(window).bind("resize", function(){
        divresize(); //THIRD FUNCTION CALL? ON WINDOW RESIZE
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Roy Scheffers! So the first line is just stating that the function will only be defined after the document is rendered and all my referenced divs are available. The "firing" that's taking place is just of the function being defined, after all the pieces it needs are available.

I take it this is a line of code you'd want anytime you're working with HTML elements that need to be rendered first?

Comment: Yes that's what this `$(document).ready(function() {  // code here }` part does. It waits for the html document to load, and then any code within it is loaded.

Comment: `$(window).bind("resize", function(){ // code here }` Here the resizing is defined. Code within it only runs when the window is resized. Not earlier. I hope this helps.